# How to properly display all Unicode characters with PyQt?

Tags: c++, qt, unicode, pyqt

I'm trying to display a few Unicode characters on PyQt (my version is PyQt4, from Anaconda on Windows). For some reason, it works all right with a C++ project on Qt Creator (but using Qt5), but some characters show the white box when using PyQt.

#### Test Cases:

As a test, I've made an simple app displaying the ⏩ character. I've used both the `"⏩"` literal and HTML `"<html><head/><body><p>&#9193;</p></body></html>"` on a QLabel.

This works in C++:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QChar>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel w("<html><head/><body><p>&#9193;</p></body></html>");
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

But this shows me a white box where the character should be:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic, Qt

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = QtGui.QLabel("<html><head/><body><p>&#9193;</p></body></html>")
w.show()
app.exec_()
```

I have also done a `.ui` form and loaded it both in C++ and PyQt, with the same result.

#### Question:

Is this a bug in Qt4 that was corrected in Qt5, a bug in PyQt or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: It took me a while to realize what the problem was, as my browser is also showing a white box !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a bug, and you're not doing anything wrong.

Just to confirm, the character you're trying to display is this:

```
>>> import html, unicodedata
>>> unicodedata.name(html.unescape('&#9193;'))
'BLACK RIGHT-POINTING DOUBLE TRIANGLE'
```

So, a pretty obscure character that won't be supported by most fonts - including the default font on my system, which is "DejaVu Sans". And in fact I wasn't able to find a single font currently on my system that can display it. I had to install the "Symbola" font to get it to display properly.

Presumably, on your system, Qt5 and Qt4 programs don't use the same default application font, which explains the difference in behaviour for the PyQt4 test case.

**EDIT**:

I tested on Windows - the character doesn't display there either, and for the same reason: none of the existing fonts supports the character. So I installed "Symbola", but I had to explicitly set it as the application font in PyQt in order to get the character to display correctly. For some reason, the [usual mechanisms for partial font subsitution on Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb688134.aspx) don't seem to be working properly - but I have no idea why. The only program that automatically displays the character correctly is Firefox.

Comment: I have already checked and both are using MS Shell Dlg 2 and it isn't being replaced by another font family. For now I'm changing the replacing the "bad" symbols for more common ones, but the question isn't answered yet.

Comment: @RonanPaixão. See the edit to my answer. "MS Shell Dlg 2" is a *logical* font, which probably resolves to something like "Tahoma" or "Microsoft Sans Serif" on your system. In order to display the problem character, Windows will have to load it from some other font.